$10$-digit numbers divisible by $66667$.
Let us consider the set $S$ of $10$-digit numbers whose digits are only allowed to be taken from the set $\{3,4,5,6,7,8\}$. Let $S'$ be the subset of $S$ such that its elements are divisible by $66667$. Then what is the cardinality of $S'$ ?
I think this problem is similar to This one, so I try to solve this problem as follows:
Let $abcdefghij$ be an element of $S'$. Then we have that $3\cdot 66667\cdot abcde-2\cdot(100000\cdot abcde+fghij)$ is also divisible by $66667$. We can thus write
$$
abcde=2\cdot fghij+k\cdot 66667,
$$
where $k$ is an integer. Note that both $5$-digit numbers are greater than $30000$ and are
less than $100000$, so we further see that it is only possible for the the cases when $k=0,-1,-2$.
Unfortunately, I got stuck here. I think the factor $2$ before $fghij$ is annoying, and I have no idea how to step forward then.
Thanks in advance for any helpful answer.

If it's any help, I bruteforced the counts for each $k=0,-1,-2$. They are $342, 243, 192$, total $777$. Notice: $243=3^5$ and $192=2^6 \cdot 3$. (By the way, at first I forgot one $6$ in the number, i.e. used $6667$, and then the outcome was $888 = 342 + 162 + 384$). Can we "reverse-engineer" the solution from the answer :D

@ploosu2 My friend help me check that the answer is indeed $777$ using python. I am curious about how did you work out the answer (

With Python too just iterating over all possibilities for the digits $fghij$ and checking if the produced $abcde$ has only the allowed digits. Code: https://www.online-python.com/vV1JLRGtUw

Let's assume $x=\overline{a_1a_2a_3a_4a_5a_6a_7a_8a_9a_{10}}$. Then,
$$66667 \mid 10^5\times \overline{a_1a_2a_3a_4a_5}+\overline{a_6a_7a_8a_9a_{10}} \implies 66667 \mid 2\times \overline{a_6a_7a_8a_9a_{10}}-\overline{a_1a_2a_3a_4a_5}.$$
If $\overline{a_1a_2a_3a_4a_5} > 2\times \overline{a_6a_7a_8a_9a_{10}}$, then,
$$0<\overline{a_1a_2a_3a_4a_5}-2\times \overline{a_6a_7a_8a_9a_{10}}\leq 88888-66666=22222.$$
So, we must have: $2\times \overline{a_6a_7a_8a_9a_{10}} \geq\overline{a_1a_2a_3a_4a_5}.$
Thus, three cases happen.

CASE $1$: $2\times \overline{a_6a_7a_8a_9a_{10}} =\overline{a_1a_2a_3a_4a_5}. $
First of all note that $a_6$ must be either $3$ or $4$. Let's assume $a_6=3.$ The next observation is that we must have $a_{10} \in \{3,4,7,8\}$ (Why?). Whatever possible number $a_{10}$ is, $a_5$ is uniquely determined. Moreover, whatever possible number $a_{10}$ is, we have $4$ options for choosing $a_9.$ For example if $a_{10}=4,$ then $a_9 \in \{3,4,7,8\}$ and if $a_{10}=7,$ then $a_9 \in \{3,6,7,8\}$. In any way, $a_4$ is also uniquely determined. Again, note that whatever possible number $a_{9}$ is, we have $4$ options for choosing $a_8.$ For example if $a_{9}=6,$ then $a_8 \in \{3,6,7,8\}$, and in a similar way, the same goes for $a_7$. Hence in this manner, we have $4^4$ options.
Now, if $a_6=4$, then $a_7$ must be either $3$ or $4$ (why?). If $a_7=3$, we have $4^3$ more options (Why?) and if $a_7=4,$ then $a_8$ must be either $4$ or $3$. If $a_8=3$, we have $4^2$ more options and if $a_8=4$, then $a_9$ is either $3$ or $4$. If $a_9=3,$ we have $4$ more options, and finally if $a_9=4$, we have two ultimate possible options, $44444$ and $44443$.
Therefore, we have
$4^4+4^3+4^2+4+2=342$ options in this case.

CASE $2$: $2\times \overline{a_6a_7a_8a_9a_{10}} =\overline{a_1a_2a_3a_4a_5}+66667. $
In this manner, we have:
$$10^4(2a_6-a_1-6)+10^3(2a_7-a_2-6)+10^2(2a_8-a_3-6) \\ +10^1(2a_9-a_4-6)+(2a_{10}-a_5-7)=0.$$
Since $-9\leq 2a_{10}-a_5-7 \leq 6$, we conclude that $ 2a_{10}-a_5-7=0$ (consider module $10$).
Similarly (considering module $10$), we obtain that for $1\leq i \leq 4$, $2a_{i+5}-a_i-6=0$, which implies we have $3^5$ options in this case (note that each equation has $3$ pairs of solutions!).

CASE $3$: $2\times \overline{a_6a_7a_8a_9a_{10}} =\overline{a_1a_2a_3a_4a_5}+133334. $
In this case, it is very easy to show that $a_6=8$. A quick observation also shows that $a_{10} \in \{4,5,6\}$ (Can you see why $7,8,3$ are not possible? Just look at possible values of $a_5$ and the sum with $133334$). Whatever $a_{10}$ is, $a_5$ is uniquely determined. Now, it's very easy to show that $a_7, a_8,a_9 \in \{3,4,5,8\}$, which forces $a_1, a_2,a_3,a_4$ to be uniquely determined (You can test a few sets of the mentions numbers to see how  $a_1, a_2,a_3,a_4$ are determined).
Hence, in this case, we have $3 \times 4^3$ options.

Finally, the answer is $342+3 \times 4^3+3^5=777.$
